# ¿Cómo configurar un paquete de npm?

Tags: javascript, html, npm

Instale este [Paquete](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier) dado a que google me lo recomiendo para optimizar mejor el html comprimiendolo, pero tengo un problema dado a que quiero configurar algunos parámetros como por ejemplo el `collapseWhitespace` para esto ejecute en la consola el siguiente comando `html-minifier --collapseWhitespace=true` y también intente `html-minifier --collapse-whitespace=true` pero ninguno anduvo.

Answer (score 3):

Porbaste con el loader de html-minifier?

[Link del paquete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier-loader)

```
npm install html-minifier html-minifier-loader --save
```

Ejemplo de webpackconfig.js

```
    module: {
    loaders: [
        {    test: /\.html$/,
             loader: 'raw-loader!html-minifier-loader'
        }
    ]
},
'html-minifier-loader': {
    removeComments: false,
    collapseWhitespace: true,
    conservativeCollapse: true,
    preserveLineBreaks: true
}
```

Comment: una pregunta, nunca antes use paquetes de npm para desarrollo web, deberia añadir un archivo .js en el root de mi web ?

Comment: Quiza esto te sea de ayuda... http://dontkry.com/posts/code/using-npm-on-the-client-side.html

Comment: @Pachi Estas herramientas son escritas en JS, pero son para ser usadas en tiempo de desarrollo, no en el navegador. Por tanto no tienes que añadirlas a tu aplicación

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con `gulp`, usando la libreria `uglify`

```
const gulp = require('gulp')

const concat = require('gulp-concat')
const runSeq = require('run-sequence')
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
const watch = require('gulp-watch')

gulp.task('build', function () {
    runSeq('copy-vendors','minify')
});

gulp.task('minify', function() {
    gulp.src('src/js/*.js')// mimifica todos los js
      .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/js'))

    gulp.src('src/css/*.css')
      .pipe(concat('app.min.css')) // mimifica todos los css
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/css'))

    gulp.src('src/views/*.html')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/views')) // mimifica todos los html
})
```